# Using "I am writing to..." with "request"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage, verbs

I have encountered the phrase "I am writing to inform..." several times in an E-mail.  However, I have never seen this phrase used with any verb other than "inform" before.  Thus, I am not very confident in the validity of the following sentence:

"I am writing to request your permission to organize an interview..."

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me if the sentence above is within the norm of polite business language and if I could use the phrase with any verb other than inform.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="writing+to+you+to+request"&oq="writing+to+you+to+request"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.21097j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#ip=1

Comment: Why request **for**? Please look up the verb request used in sample sentences. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use lot of different words here, though as @Lambie points out, the **for** in your example is not needed/normal.

For example:

I am writing to ask ...

I am writing to say ...

I am writing to let you know ...

I am writing to query whether ...